# Javascript to allow a whitelist of URL arguments only

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a whitelist of allowed url args/query strings so any provided args in the url that are not in my whitelist are deleted from the url.

Here is my code.

```
var paramsString = "2=lol&q=how&44=slap&topic=api&1=tr&view=media"; //test url args
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsString);

//this whitelist of args are the only args to be allowed in the url
var url_args_whitelist = [
"beforeafter",
"catid",
"childforums",
"display",
"element_id",
"element_type",
"exactname",
"filter_mediaType",
"filter_order",
"filter_order_Dir",
"filter_search",
"filter_tag",
"format",
"id",
"Itemid",
"layout",
"limit",
"limitstart",
"messageid",
"more",
"option",
"order",
"ordering",
"quality",
"query",
"recently",
"recip",
"reply_id",
"return",
"searchdate",
"searchf",
"searchphrase",
"searchuser",
"searchword",
"sortby",
"start",
"task",
"tmpl",
"token",
"view"
];

for (let p of searchParams) {
//if the url argument is not in our whitelist of allowed arguments then delete it
  searchParams.delete(p[0]);
}

console.log("whitelist output: ", searchParams.toString() );
```

How can I make my code check against my whitelist and then run my delete function to remove the junk url args.

Comment: Do you want to attach this function to an html input?

Comment: Not sure how that is a dupe.... OP is already using method to get it

Comment: I hope you are running this server side, knowing that anyone who visits your site can modify JavaScript client side.

Comment: @ansielf Yes ofcourse :) It is a Javascript web worker script. ( Cloudflare : https://cloudflareworkers.com/ )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Explained

Okay, so here's a pretty simple implementation, using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function, it's simple, clean and if anything, thanks to using this approach, it doesn't cause for the value(s) of `searchParams` to change.

Furthermore, I'd like to add that I tried to change nearly as little as possible, I made the assumption that you didn't want side effects in your code.

### Edit

If you'd like to understand the ES6-style implementation that I've provided, then you can look more into topics such as [currying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying), for this topic specifically I suggest reading some content produced by [Eric Elliott](https://medium.com/@_ericelliott), finally if you want to learn more about the syntax such as arrow functions, I might suggest [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```js
var paramsString = "2=lol&q=how&44=slap&topic=api&1=tr&view=media"; //test url args
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsString);

// This whitelist of args are the only args to be allowed in the url.
var url_args_whitelist = [
  "beforeafter", "catid", "childforums", "display", "element_id",
  "element_type", "exactname", "filter_mediaType", "filter_order",
  "filter_order_Dir", "filter_search", "filter_tag", "format", "id",
  "Itemid", "layout", "limit", "limitstart", "messageid", "more",
  "option", "order", "ordering", "quality", "query", "recently",
  "recip", "reply_id", "return", "searchdate", "searchf", "searchphrase",
  "searchuser", "searchword", "sortby", "start", "task", "tmpl", "token", "view"
];

// Create an Array from searchParams, then reduce it via ensuring that each 
// key exists within the 'url_args_whitelist' Array, finally joining using 
// an '&' symbol. 
var cleanURL = Array.from(searchParams).reduce(function(array, sub) {
  var key = sub[0], value = sub[1];

  // Check the argument exists in the URL, if so, then push it onto the new array.
  if (url_args_whitelist.indexOf(key) > -1) array.push(key + '=' + value);

  return array;
}, []).join("&");

// Finally a more ES6 style approach, basically a one liner.
const clean = a => l => a.filter(o => l.includes(o[0])).map(o => o.join("=")).join("&");

// Results.
console.log("whitelist output:", cleanURL);
console.log("es6 output:", clean(Array.from(searchParams))(url_args_whitelist));
console.log("old output:", searchParams.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you for your soloution! and for thinking ahead about unwanted side effects and bugs with the code i really appreciate that it works flawlessly i have marked your detailed soloution as the answer, All the other answers given do also work but i find yours to be the best for my usage scenario thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

I would just loop over the array and use reduce to get the keys that you care about. I would not try to delete anything.

```
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsString);

var url_args_whitelist = [
"beforeafter",
"catid",
"childforums",
"display"
];

var whiteList = url_args_whitelist.reduce( function (obj, key) {
  var value = searchParams.get(key)
  if (value) {
    obj[key] = value
  }
  return obj;
}, {});
```

But if you want to keep it with the url params it does have a [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/delete) method. So loop over all the entries and than delete it.

```
searchParams.forEach(function(value, key) {
  if (url_args_whitelist.indexOf(key) === -1) {
    searchParams.delete(key)
  }
});
```

Comment: Deleting from an object while iterating it breaks the iteration (it shifts indexes around). Do not follow the second example.

Answer (score 2):

You have to get your URL, split it in keys and values then filter the keys against the whitelist. In the end you compose the new URL and perform a redirect:

```
const query = window.location.search.replace('?', '');

const result = query
  .split('&')
  .map(token => {
    const [key, value] = token.split('=');
    return {key, value};
  })
  .filter(keyval => {
    return url_args_whitelist.indexOf(keyval.key) !== -1;
  })
  .map(keyval => {
    return [keyval.key, keyval.value].join('=');
  })
  .join('&');

window.location.search = '?' + result;
```

Here is a working example:

```js
/* let's suppose these are your query params */

let query = '?childforums=123&abc=345';

query = query.replace('?', '');


var url_args_whitelist = [
"beforeafter",
"catid",
"childforums",
"display",
"element_id",
"element_type",
"exactname",
"filter_mediaType",
"filter_order",
"filter_order_Dir",
"filter_search",
"filter_tag",
"format",
"id",
"Itemid",
"layout",
"limit",
"limitstart",
"messageid",
"more",
"option",
"order",
"ordering",
"quality",
"query",
"recently",
"recip",
"reply_id",
"return",
"searchdate",
"searchf",
"searchphrase",
"searchuser",
"searchword",
"sortby",
"start",
"task",
"tmpl",
"token",
"view"
];



const result = query
  .split('&')
  .map(token => {
    const [key, value] = token.split('=');
    return {key, value};
  })
  .filter(keyval => {
     return url_args_whitelist.indexOf(keyval.key) !== -1;
  })
  .map(keyval => {
    return [keyval.key, keyval.value].join('=');
  })
  .join('&');

console.log('input:', query);
console.log('output:', result);
```

Comment: As much as I really like this solution, I don't think that the OP can make sense of this, I'm **assuming** that the OP wouldn't be familiar with things such as arrow functions, or at least provide some sources to documentation? Apart from that, good answer! Clean & concise.

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V yeah this is not trivial, but I think that it's a good use of functional programming and we should start to see more code like this. I also tried to keep the code clean, for example using only block functions

Comment: I couldn't agree more! That's the only reason why I didn't use a similar approach, I assumed the OP wouldn't have been able to make sense of it, possibly, you're totally right, and I personally love that FP is becoming more and more mainstream! +1 from me.

Comment: The problem would be the complexity and performance of the code. You are iterating through the code a lot more times than really necessary.

Comment: @DhananjaiPai there is no performance issue on iterating on the same array several times, it just becomes 3*O(n), which si just O(n). If we iterated on it just once and performed all the operations in the same loop, the performance was the same!

Comment: 3*O(n) may be O(n), but 3*1000 is not 1000. I agree that the code is legible, but it is not optimal :)

Comment: This is just theoretically. In practice, javascript performs a better optimization using the old classic for loop, and you can find some publication on the net. But in my opinion, better having a cleaner code than gaining 1ms :)

Comment: @CristianTraìna Thank you for sharing your soloution it is also a soloution that works i wish i could mark it as the answer with JO3-W3B-D3V also being the correct answer. I have upvoted you for your awesome contribution.

Answer (score 2):

The most optimal way to do it is to store the whitelist urls as an object, instead of an array. Since then, it would act as a hashMap and you would not have to search if the key is included [with O(n) complexity each time]

```js
var paramsString = "2=lol&q=how&44=slap&topic=api&1=tr&view=media"; //test url args
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(paramsString);

var url_args_whitelist = {
    "topic": true,
    "catid": true,
    // repeat for other values
    "token": true,
    "view": true,
};

var resultParams = new URLSearchParams();

for (let p of searchParams) {
  if (url_args_whitelist[p[0]]) {
    resultParams.append(...p)
  }
}

console.log("whitelist output: ", resultParams.toString() );
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are asking for something like this:

```
   for (let p of searchParams) {
      if (!url_args_whitelist.includes(p[0])) {
        searchParams.delete(p[0]);
      }
    }

    console.log("whitelist output: ", searchParams.toString() );
```

Comment: if you delete in in-place, it affects the iterator and incorrect results would be produced. Run the above code against the question